# Returning a two element tuple where the first element is the combined elements of a bigram

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment using NLP, where I'm analyzing text from Harry Potter. The first element is a bigram.

I'm trying to convert this:

```
[(('Uncle', 'Vernon'), 108)]
```

into this:

```
[(('Uncle Vernon'), 108)]
```

Ideally, I'd like to get rid the comma and combine the two words together into a single phrase. I've tried using the split method, but since it is a tuple, I cannot. Any advice?

Note that the second element (`108`) is simply a count of how many times this phrase has appeared in the text.

Comment: Just use `' '.join(t)` where `t` is your tuple of strings.  This will work on an arbitrary number of strings in the tuple.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! I'm still new to Python, so I didn't think of that. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking with an `f-string`. Additionally, `(val)` simply results in `val`, thus, `[(('Uncle Vernon'), 108)]` is equivalent to `[('Uncle Vernon', 108)]`. However, if you do want to preserve the tuple, you can add a comma:

```
data = [(('Uncle', 'Vernon'), 108)]
result = [((f'{a} {b}',), c) for (a, b), c in data]
```

Output:

```
[(('Uncle Vernon',), 108)]
```

Comment: Better:  `' '.join(t)` where `t` is the tuple of strings.  This will also work on an arbitrary number of strings in the tuple, whereas the posted solution only works on exactly 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is the opposite of what you need here, as the strings are already splitted...

What you want is [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which takes an iterable and concatenates it to one string. Something like:

```py
>>> data = [(('Uncle', 'Vernon'), 108)]
>>> res = [(" ".join(a), b) for a, b in data]
>>> res
[('Uncle Vernon', 108)]
```